Why this code works in the Java inheritance demo?
I am new to Java and am working on an inheritance demo. I am puzzled because when I attempt to access the private field of the superclass with name or this.name, the compiler correctly reports an error as many toturials told that subclass have no access to private field in superclass. However, when I use super.name, there are no errors, and calling this method seems to update the name field in the subclass object.
I am using IDEA with jdk 18, and the full code of my demo is shown below
public class IV_extend_class_ver2 {
    public static class Person {
        //field
        private String name = "Person";

        //default Constructor

        //method
        public String getName(){   return this.name;   }
        public void setName(String name){   this.name = name;   }
    }



    //Worker extends from Person
    public static class  Worker extends Person {
        private int salary;

        public int getSalary() {   return this.salary; }
        public void setSalary(int salary) {   this.salary = salary;   }

        //access the private member in superclass
        public String hello() {
            return "Hello, " + super.name;
            // If write name or this.name,  an error would get in IDEA
            // But if I wirte super.name，it compiles successfully
            // and if I call hello() in next part, it works 
        }
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Worker man = new Worker();
        System.out.println(man.hello());
        man.setName("Bob");
        System.out.println(man.hello());
    }
}


and the results would be
Hello, Person
Hello, Bob

Thanks
Could someone explain why this is happening? I am confused about two points:

Why does super.name work in this program compared with another two statements?
Why it's the name field of the subclass changes rather than the superclass, as super should refer to?


You are using inner classes. Have you tried making classes Person and Worker completely separate, independent classes? In other words create a file Person.java for the Person class and a separate Worker.java file for the Worker class and then see if you get the same behavior.

Thanks Abra, when I seperate them into two seperate class files, 'super.name' no longer compilable.

@Abra where does it state this behavior for inner classes in the docs?

@rb612 I don't know where this behavior for inner classes is stated, that's why I posted a comment and not an answer, i.e. it was more of a suggestion. Maybe in the Java SE Specifications?

calling getName() would probably be more appropriate...

There are a few misunderstandings.
Private fields are not inherited, so Worker does not have name as one of its members.

Members of a class that are declared private are not inherited by subclasses of that class.

That said, the value of name still exists in an instance of Worker. After all, other methods like getName and setName needs that to work. See also: Do subclasses inherit private fields? This should answer your second question - there is no "field of the subclass" and "field of the superclass". There is ever only one field called name in this code.
name is accessible in Worker. private disallows access from outside of the top-level class. The top-level class in this case is IV_extend_class_ver2.

Otherwise, the member or constructor is declared private. Access is permitted only when one of the following is true:

Access occurs from within the body of the top level class or interface that encloses the declaration of the member or constructor.
[...]


See also: Why do inner classes make private methods accessible?
Even though name is accessible in Worker, not every form of access is valid.

You cannot write this.name, because this is of type Worker, and as mentioned before, Worker does not have a field named name, so the expression is invalid.
(in this case Primary refers to the expression this)

The type of the Primary must be a reference type T, or a compile-time error occurs.
The meaning of the field access expression is determined as follows:

[...]

If the identifier does not name an accessible member field in type T, then the field access is undefined and a compile-time error occurs.




It is also not valid to use a simple name (i.e. just writing name) because the scope (not the same thing as accessibility!) of name is the body of the class Person.

The scope of a declaration of a member m declared in or inherited by a class or interface C is the entire body of C, including any nested class or interface declarations.


If an expression name consists of a single Identifier, then:

[...]
if there is exactly one declaration denoting either a local variable, formal parameter, exception parameter, or field in scope at the point at which the identifier occurs, then the expression name refers to the in-scope variable.
Otherwise, a compile-time error occurs.



super.name is valid, because this form searches for fields in the superclass. You can think of this as ((Person)this).name.

The form super.Identifier refers to the field named Identifier of the current object, but with the current object viewed as an instance of the superclass of the current class.



